# What are the mechanisms behind this function?

Tags: c++, function

I wrote a small program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int raw(int &x) {
    cout<<x<<endl;
    cout<<&x<<endl;
}

int main () {
    int s= 1;
    int &z=s;
    raw(s);
    raw(z);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is(as expected):

```
1
0x7fff5ed36894
1
0x7fff5ed36894
```

It works as I expect it to be but I am curious about how this is implemented internally. Is it function overloading or something else or one of the function is a wrapper around the other function to provide user-friendliness or the compiler does casting while on its own?

Comment: `z` is an alias for `s`. Whatever you do on `z` or with `z` after its initialization, you do it on the object it is bound to. So `raw(s)` and `raw(z)` must necessarily give the same output, as they work on the same input (assuming referential transparency here)

Comment: @AndyProwl I know reference is an alias. I want to know how they are implemented internally. I already mentioned in question that "they work as expected".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how it looks in assembler:

```
    int s= 1;
002044A8  mov         dword ptr [s],1  
    int &z=s;
002044AF  lea         eax,[s]  
002044B2  mov         dword ptr [z],eax  
    raw(s);
002044B5  lea         eax,[s]  
002044B8  push        eax  
002044B9  call        raw (020110Eh)  
002044BE  add         esp,4  
    raw(z);
002044C1  mov         eax,dword ptr [z]  
002044C4  push        eax  
002044C5  call        raw (020110Eh)
```

LEA (in `lea eax,[s]`) means **Load Effective Address** so you can see how `z` effectively contains a pointer to location of `s`.

push instructions that prepare the arguments before the function call clearly show that you get (the same) pointer as an input in both cases.

This is non-optimized code.

Answer (score 5):

When the compiler produces code for your program, when it sees the `&` saying that this is a reference, it really produces a pointer variable [or something, in machine code, that resembles a pointer].

So `z` as such will hold the address of `s`.

When you call `raw(s)`, the compiler says "Ah, so the parameter to raw is a reference which means the address of `s`". When you do `raw(z)`, the compiler says "Ah, we have a reference already, so lets just pass the content of `z`", which since you set it to `s` earlier, is the same address as `s`.

This is exactly as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Internally this

```
int s= 1;
int &z=s;
raw(s);
raw(z);
```

Is optimized to this:

```
int s = 1;
raw(s);
raw(s);
```

Because after you do `int &z = s;`  variable `z` will be aliased to s to end end of its lifetime. So basically it will be the same as s.

Comment: What will happen if we have a `const` reference. This can't be done then. Can it be?

Comment: I meant this: `const int &z=s;`

Comment: In this case it will be optimized anyway but only if there will be no compile errors but in your example there will be. And this assignment `const int &z=s;`  automatically casts from non-const to const